# How to hide dropdown list in datalist when is empty

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I have an input and datalist as autocomplete search with dynamic data.
When I typed "F" on my input I search with my endpoints those elements which match with my query. Such as

```html
<form >
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Results are show correctly when you search for something like "F".
[image]
Results after delete "F":

[image]

My issue is when I delete my query from my input and query is empty "", I am still getting the same results and I can not hide this dropdown until I  have clicked on anywhere.

How could I hide this list dropdown until I decided start type again?

I am using Google chrome **Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

Comment: Must be a browsers specific issue...works for me on Chrome

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Google chrome Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit) @TakitIsy

Comment: I am using chrome and it does not work @LGSon

Comment: Well, I'm using Chrome 65.0.3325.181 (64-bit) and it does work!

Comment: I am using Chrome 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it works just fine

Comment: I have just updated to Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it is not working yet @TakitIsy Did you try what  I am describing above or just try if datalist show results?

Comment: I have just updated to Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it is not working yet @LGSon Did you try what  I am describing above or just try if datalist show results?

Comment: In above code snippet, when I enter `F` it shows 2 items, when delete `F` it shows none

Comment: Do you do that without click in anywhere when delete F? If you click whatever you want dropdown list dissapear but if you don not do anything the of two are still there for me. @LGSon

Comment: I click in the box, add `F`, 2 items shows, then push backspace so `F` deletes, no items shows

Comment: Same as LGSon, no problem for me.

Comment: thanks, I am going to find out where the problem is.